# Set the WordPress thumbnail in php code (automatically)

Tags: wordpress, youtube, set, thumbnails

I'm struggling with this for a while now...

I have written a function that automatically gets the thumbnail of the youtube video that i embed in my code. i saved this to a variable $img.

My question now is how can i set $img to be my post thumbnail.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Easy process should be save the thumbnail as an custom field, for say "image". Then call this custom field in theme where you need like

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "image", true); ?>" alt="" />
```

You could also attach that image with post.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to display your image in your post before any other image. Display it either in your editor, or inside your single.php loop. then use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-post-thumbnail/.

You can even hide it using CSS or `img` tag attributes.